# What ship is this in Sasebo, Japan Harbor, Korean War Era?

Tags: military, japan, naval, ships, korean-war

[image: ship in harbor]Identification of Ship in Sasebo, Japan Harbor, Korean War Era from my Flickr page
https://www.flickr.com/photos/photolibrarian/51241341355/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: The link to the high rez photo is great, but could you please edit to include an image of it here as well, so people aren't asked to click through to get a glance? Also, it would be helpful to know exactly what you already know and/or suspect about it, and exactly what it is you'd like to know.

Comment: This is all the information I have.

Answer (score 9):

That is the [Camano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camano-class_cargo_ship) class Light Cargo Ship [USS Sharps (AKL-10)](http://www.navsource.org/archives/09/49/49139.htm).

She started out her life as an Army freight-supply vessel in 1944. The US Navy acquired her in 1947 and she was commissioned as Miscellaneous Auxiliary USS Sharps (AG-139), and reclassified as a light cargo ship (AKL-10) in 1949.

The Sharps served in the Korean War earning three battle stars. The Sharps was decommissioned in 1955 and transferred to South Korea where it was commissioned as ROKS Kun San (AKL-908).

Here's a photo of the Sharps in Sasebo in 1952:
[image: USS Sharps in Sasebo in 1952]

Source for photo and info: Navsource.org service ship photo archive.

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be a Bullfinch class mine sweeper/trawler of which there were 17 altogether.  Source is Janes Fighting Ships 1942 and Janes Fighting Ships 1944-1945. All of the class were commissioned from civilian use in 1940.  Most were built in the late 1920's into the late 1930's.  These were all trawlers built mostly in New England with slight variations between each.

Since the photograph is at Sasebo, it is probably postwar.  By that time there were only four or five still in commission, the rest having be stricken and sold off in 1944 -1945.  Also of the 17 in the class only four were in the Pacific, the rest served as harbor minesweepers at ports on the US east coast.  Superficial record search finds none of the Pacific stationed of this type venturing farther west than Iwo Jima but a photo at Sasebo would seem to belie that.  Possibly transferred to Japanese or the South Koreans, but I've no information on that.

Only photo I could find, this from the 1944-1945 Janes, typical of the class, this is USS Goshawk (AM-79)

[image]

**And** I stand corrected, see User32229's answer.  Thanks for the better eye than mine.

Comment: Could it be one of the stricken vessels? I see no hull number on the photo.

Comment: You can see a blurred hull number above and to the left of the anchor at the bow,  Late war numbers tended to be small, not at all like that on the Goshawk shown.  First thing I tried was to read the number, but, alas.